# How to use uglify js efficiently?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs

I am looking into using uglifyjs to minimize my webpack bundle

currently my bundle is: 1.13 MB

I have installed webpack bundle analyzer and have booted it up and seen the stats it has thrown up.

For example my basket/index.js is: stat size: 5.16kb, parsed size: 5.38kb,and gzipped size is: 1017b.

I have a couple of questions.

**1.** can I get this file down to the gzipped size?

**2.** can I just run `uglifyjs --compress filename` to achieve this?

**3.** why is the parsed size bigger than the stat size?

**4.** will this make an iota of difference to the bundle size/performance?

Comment: What do you mean gzipped size? If your talking about on the wire compression you don't compress the file, the web server will gzip it when it's served to the client (if you have compression enabled). You don't want to zip your actual js file, minify yes, zip no

Comment: @Liam ok, but how does uglify get involved with making the file smaller and thus making the bundle smaller?

Comment: Uglify makes a file smaller by minifying it (not compressing it in the classic sense). Have a look at this [What is the real difference between a minified and uncompressed file? What are the benefits of each?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232586/what-is-the-real-difference-between-a-minified-and-uncompressed-file-what-are-t)

Comment: @Liam ok sure. but also isn't the point of minifying to make the file smaller and thus saving download time and making it more performant? so I guess my question is, how do I achieve this with uglify? do I run uglify and then save the output file to my bundle?

Comment: That's what uglify **should** do. If it's not we'd need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem to explain why it's not. If the file is webpacked already then you may be trying to minify twice, this will not make it smaller. You can't make a minified file more minifed.